# Is there a way to check the spelling of words in a character vector?

Tags: r, text, spell-checking

The text to be checked is in Greek, but I would like to know if it can be done for English words too. My initial idea is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624477/get-in-column-b-the-words-of-column-a-that-are-not-in-dictionary), and I have already found a way to do it using VBA. But I wonder if there's a way to do it using R. If there isn't a way in R, do you think of something better than Excel-vba?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, OpenOffice ships with a dictionary that entries stored in a text file.  You can read that and remove the word definitions to create your word list.

This was tested on v3.0; the file location may have shifted, and the filename will change depending on which dictionary you want.

```
library(stringr)
dict <- readLines("C:/Program Files/OpenOffice.org 3/share/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/174.tmp_/dict-en.oxt/th_en_US_v2.dat")
is_word <- str_detect(dict, "^[^(]")
words <- str_split_fixed(dict[is_word], "\\|", 2)
words <- words[,1]
```

This list contains some multi-word phrases.  You may prefer to split on the first space, and take unique values.  You probably also want to write `words` to file, to save repeating yourself.

Once this is done, checking a word is as easy as

```
c("persnickety", "sqwrzib") %in% words      # TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

There exists an open source GNU spell checker called [Aspell](http://aspell.net/) with suppot for various languages. This is a command line program which I basically use for scanning bunches of text files at once (then the output is just given to the console).
But there also exists a [C API](http://aspell.net/man-html/Through-the-C-API.html#Through-the-C-API) and perhaps more interesting for you a [Pipe mode](http://aspell.net/man-html/Through-A-Pipe.html#Through-A-Pipe) which accepts streams of texts and outputs to the standard output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a windows binary for Aspell?

Comment: Yes, there is, and the windows binary is what I am using: http://aspell.net/win32/

Comment: Is there a way to use it from R? I saw this http://www.omegahat.org/Aspell/ but I read that `There is currently no binary version for Windows`

Comment: I think Hunspell should be used instead of Aspell today; it certainly works on Windows, but you may need to compile it by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't heard of any R Version. And truly, Hunspell is the more up-to-date thing, but as you just need a spell check, Aspell is probably enough. If you get it to work for your problem.